# How to pass context from view to action in html file in django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I am passing context from view.py file

```
def change_password(request,pk=None):
    user = MyUser.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=user, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)  
            return render(request, "nurse/change_password.html", {"user_id":user.id})     // passing user_id as context
```

I can see this value in my html file

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label allign col-sm-3" > {{user_id}} Old Password </label>    // user_id is giving the right value
</div>
```

But when i try to fetch the same in action than it is not working:

```
<form class="form-horizontal login-box2" action="{% url 'booking:change_password' user_id %}" role="form" method="post">   // not getting user_id here
    <div class="form-group">  
        <label class="control-label allign col-sm-3" > {{user_id}} Old Password </label>      // getting user_id here
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <li> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary f-w-b f-s-18">Change</button> </li>
    </div>
</form>
```

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Thanks

**EDITED**

adding urls.py code:

```
url(r'^change_password/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.change_password,name='change_password'),
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? errors? invalid results?

Comment: No result.. when i hard code user_id to any integer than i am getting results.

Comment: Are you sure user_id passing when GET request ?

Comment: GET or POST? not getting user_id in POST action

Comment: Can you add your urls.py file?

Comment: code of urls.py added

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean by 'no result'. Do you get a `NoReverseMatch Error`? If so, you should show the error. You seem to be using namespaces (i.e. 'booking:change_password', but you haven't shown how you are including the urls, so we can't tell whether you have done that correctly or not. Finally, your view doesn't show what you return for GET requests.

Comment: Note that by fetching the user with `user = MyUser.objects.get(pk=pk)`, you allow users to change passwords for *any* user by changing the pk in the url. If you want to have a view that does this, you must make sure that only authorised users can access it (e.g. by using the [`permission_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator) decorator).